# Cosmos DB Index size is greater than Data Size

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a partitioned collection in cosmos db with custom indexing policy (approx. 30 include fields) and consistent index mode. When collection data size reached high level was decided to remove some docs (~50k) from collection and move to other storage.

After removal data size reduced significantly but Index size keep the same and even start increasing.. That seems very strange because I expect index size to reduce the same as data size. Isn't it removed when data is removed? Should I do something additional to remove Indexes? Is it even ok that data size is less than index size?

Screenshot for azure collection metrics:
[image]

Deletion was done by js stored proc

```
    function bulkDeleteByCondition() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var query = "SELECT root._self FROM root";
    var responseBody = {
        deleted: 0,
        continuation: true
    };

    tryQueryAndDelete();

    function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation) {
        var requestOptions = { continuation: continuation };

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(`Failed on collection.queryDocuments: ${err} for query ${query}`);
            }

            if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
                tryDelete(retrievedDocs);
            } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {.
                tryQueryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
            } else {
                responseBody.continuation = false;
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        });

        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

    function tryDelete(documents) {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            var isAccepted = collection.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error(`Failed on collection.deleteDocument: ${err} for query ${query}`);
                }

                responseBody.deleted++;
                documents.shift();
                tryDelete(documents);
            });

            if (!isAccepted) {
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            tryQueryAndDelete();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the size has reduced by now. It seems to take a long time for the space to be unallocated after deletion, possibly due to fragmentation.   I have a collection with a 2 day TTL and despite most of the document structure being excluded from indexing the index size is usually near the same as the documents.

Comment: no still not. Index size is stil grater than data size

Comment: Try raising a support request with MS.   I did this and of course they said there was no problem but soon after there was a dramatic drop in the size of the index.   May have been coincidence.

Comment: @Olha, Money making leak for Azure... Any follow up?